# Error in path.expand(path) : invalid 'path' argument in R

Tags: r, path

I wrote a function to convert image to array in Rscript. When I perform `test_x <- image_prep(val_data$file_name)` I have an error saying: `Error in path.expand(path) : invalid 'path' argument in R`.

Here the function:

```
val_data <- data.frame(file_name = paste0("/run/media/invasive_60000/", val_image_array_gen$filenames)) %>% 
  mutate(class = str_extract(file_name, "class0|class1"))
# Function to convert image to array
image_prep <- function(x) {
  arrays <- lapply(x, function(path) {
    img <- image_load(path, target_size = target_size, 
                      grayscale = F # Set FALSE if image is RGB
    )
    
    x <- image_to_array(img)
    x <- array_reshape(x, c(1, dim(x)))
    x <- x/255 # rescale image pixel
  })
  do.call(abind::abind, c(arrays, list(along = 1)))
}
```

I did a verification if the directory exists:
`dir.exists("/run/media/invasive_60000/")` and it returns `TRUE`

Values of `val_image_array_gen` are coming from:

```
# Validation Dataset
val_image_array_gen <- flow_images_from_directory(directory = "/run/media/invasive_60000/",
                                                  target_size = target_size, 
                                                  color_mode = "rgb", 
                                                  batch_size = batch_size ,
                                                  seed = 123,
                                                  subset = "validation", # declare that this is the validation data
                                                  generator = train_data_gen
                                                  )
```

Comment: What is the output of `dput(val_data)`. It sounds like you are passing in invalid paths but there's no way for us to run and test the code to see what might be wrong. Where are the values from `val_image_array_gen$filenames` coming from? You tested that the directory exists, but what about the files? `file.exists(val_data$file_name)`

Comment: `dput(val_data)` outputs me: `structure(list(file_name = structure(1:530, .Label = c("/run/media/invasive_60000/cats_001.jpg" ...` Values of `val_image_array_gen$filenames` I updated the post to put the information.

Comment: `file.exists(val_data$file_name)` output the following error:`Error in file.exists(val_data$file_name) : invalid 'file' argument`

Comment: It's seems that your `val_data$file_name` values are factors somehow which doesn't seem consistent with the code you've shown. What version of R are you running? Try `file.exists(as.character(val_data$file_name))`. It's a bit difficult to guess with incomplete `dput()` output. Since we can't run `flow_images_from_directory` on our own computers, we need to see your output -- the command you used to get it really isn't that helpful in this case since we don't have your data.

Comment: The command `file.exists(as.character(val_data$file_name))` outputs `TRUE`. I am using `R version 3.6.0` in Rstudio. I actutally, tried the code of `https://rpubs.com/Argaadya/image_conv` which gives me the same error

Comment: OK. That's an older version R from 2019. Some default behaviors have changed since then. Change your paths from factors to characters with `val_data$file_name <- as.character(val_data$file_name)` and try running your code again.

Comment: Putting `val_data$file_name <- as.character(val_data$file_name)` removed the error. I just had an error when I perform ` mutate(class = str_extract(file_name, "cat|dog|panda"))` it gives me: `no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"`.

Comment: Are you piping in the data.frame to mutate? If you have a new problem, then you should start a new question to make it clear what's going on.

Comment: @MrFlick, yes I was piping in the data.frame to mutate. I will try to debug it. If I cannot resolve I will post a new question. Thanks a lot for your help :-)